# What's the difference between private setter and readonly property?

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3, setter, readonly

What's the difference between:-

```
private(set) var string: String
```

and

```
var string: String { get }
```

Comment: In the file where you have defined the class, only inside this class you can set the value of that string. You can't set this variable from anywhere.

Comment: i thought it's clear one has a set function but it's private and the other doesn't

Comment: In private set, you can set the property in a class that the property is located. But in readonly property you can set the property from nowhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Private setter means the variable can be set inside the class in which it is declared in. It will behave like readonly property outside that class's scope.

Readonly property can only be accessed, not mutated. No exception.

Answer (score 4):

`private(set) var string: String` - In this case `private(set)` only makes the set function private, while private makes both set and get functions private.

`var string: String { get }` - While in this case the variable string is read only.

Just visit this http://kostiakoval.github.io/posts/swift-public-property-with-private-setter for further clarity if you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think that: for Private var string: String, other file can't visit it. but you can change it value.
   And for var string: String {get}, other file can visit it , and you can set another property to change it value like : var stringValue = "";
var string: String {get{return stringValue}},you can change stringValue to change string.  just my thought.